# How do I use python reduce function to fill NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, fillna, functools

I have a dataframe with missing data in several columns. In some of these columns, say 'Col_A' to 'Col_D', I'd like to replace them with 0. I tried it this way:

```
reduce(lambda x : df.fillna({x : 0}, inplace=True), ['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D'])
```

but I got the error message `<lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Eventually, I changed my solution to simply

```
df[['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D']] = df[['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D']].fillna(0)
```

but I still wonder what's wrong with my previous attempt of solution.

Comment: The first parameter for reduce function, must be a lamba with two parameters,which first is the curren value, the second is the next data in frame.

Comment: it seems you should use map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is a rather odd way of achieving your goal with multiple issues that go against good programming practice

So start with a disclaimer: I WOULD NOT RECOMMEND DOING THIS BUT AM JUST ANSWERING THE QUESTION ABOUT THE BEHAVIOR OF THE FUNCTION.

With the disclaimer out of the way, this *can* be made to work with two small changes. The following should work

```
reduce(lambda _, x : df.fillna({x : 0}, inplace=True), ['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D'], 'fake')
```

Note first that we make `lambda` to take two arguments, as required by the `reduce` function. The first argument is meant to be the result of the application of the function at the previous step. Here, since we do not really care about the result of the application of the function at the previous step, but rely on side effects of `reduce` on the global (to reduce function) variable `df`  -- this being the main problems with this approach -- we make it an unnamed argument `_`. Second, we need a starting point -- the so-called initializer -- for `reduce` to work, as it will call the lambda function with this value, and the first value of the list, as the first step. If we omit the initializer as you did, it will start with the first two values of the list, thus basically missing `Col_A` to `fillna`. So, hence, we have a `'fake'` intializer passed to the `reduce` function (you can call it whatever you want, if that is not clear)